# Creating custom values/column within returned data set

Tags: mysql, union

I have a situation where I am using a UNION such as this:

```
$query = "SELECT bigimage, heading, fullarticle, dateadded FROM news ";
$query .= "WHERE (state = '" . $USER->state . "' OR state = 'ALL') AND status = 1 AND newstype != 1 AND frontpage = 1 AND bigimage > '' ";
$query .= "UNION ";
$query .= "SELECT image, eventname, details, dateadded FROM events ";
$query .= "WHERE (state = '" . $USER->state . "' OR state = 'ALL') AND status = 1 AND frontpage = 1 AND image > '' ";
$query .= "ORDER BY dateadded DESC LIMIT 10";
$restresult = mysql_query($query);
```

Now, what I am wanting to find out is which table each result comes from, so I was wondering if I could add some kind of custom result to each result returned to give me some form of indication what table it came from.

Could I add an extra "dynamic" column somehow in the returned result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$query = "SELECT bigimage, heading, fullarticle, dateadded, 'news' as TableName FROM news ";
$query .= "WHERE (state = '" . $USER->state . "' OR state = 'ALL') AND status = 1 AND newstype != 1 AND frontpage = 1 AND bigimage > '' ";
$query .= "UNION ";
$query .= "SELECT image, eventname, details, dateadded, 'event' FROM events ";
$query .= "WHERE (state = '" . $USER->state . "' OR state = 'ALL') AND status = 1 AND frontpage = 1 AND image > '' ";
$query .= "ORDER BY dateadded DESC LIMIT 10";
$restresult = mysql_query($query);
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure. Stripping out the irrelevant php code, your query could be:

```
SELECT 'news' as type, bigimage, heading, fullarticle, dateadded FROM news
WHERE (state = ? OR state = 'ALL') AND status = 1 AND newstype != 1 AND frontpage = 1 AND bigimage > ''
UNION
SELECT 'event', image, eventname, details, dateadded FROM events 
WHERE (state = ? OR state = 'ALL') AND status = 1 AND frontpage = 1 AND image > ''
ORDER BY dateadded DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

This simply adds a constant column (I called "type") with different values (I used "news" and "event" after the table from which the row was selected) depending on which side on the union the row came from.

Comment: Thanks, but why did you replace `$USER->state` with `?`?

Comment: That's the way JDBC indicates a variable placeholder, but it is also brief and doesn't clutter the answer with non-sql stuff. Obviously you would have to put the value back in your language specific way